# Docker error bind address already in use for any ip

Tags: docker

I'm trying to start a docker container on my **VPS** with exposed port, however for any port mapping I try I get below error:

```
$ docker run -p 9999:8080 nginx
$ docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint unruffled_lumiere (4d89bf7e620dee8dba0dbec861180a5452bbe416873a15d23ca618737aec97ec): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp [::]:9999: bind: address already in use.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

I get this error even if I change the first number of port to something else. Running

```
$ sudo netstat -pna | grep 9999
```

Doesn't find any address. I have tried literary 10s of different ports and always the same problem, it almost seems like the docker tires to start itself multiple times, but if I leave the -p option out it starts normally as expected. The same happens if I try to set port inside docker-compose.

EDIT (System info):

```
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
```

Comment: What environment you use this? What version of docker? What's your firewall config?

Comment: Forgot to add:
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

The firewall should be disabled and all ports should be accessible from outside.

Answer (score 0):

After checking the version again I noticed that despite manually installing the latest, the `docker -v` still returned 19. Which made me think there really is another docker instance running somehow. After uninstalling, purging and removing everything as in documentation I was still able to run `docker -v`, which made me search for all files containing word docker in it and manually removing them, after that I was able to install version 20.x and the problem with port was gone.

```
sudo apt-get purge docker-engine
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge docker-engine
rm -rf /var/lib/docker

sudo find / -name '*docker*'  <- manually remove folders that contain docker (note this also mentions docker-compose.yaml files etc, you do not need to remove such).
```

Comment: Did you have docker installed via snap?