# Two docker instances/daemons running on linux machine

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-18.04

So I have been experiencing an issue where there are two Docker instances (daemons) that are running at the same time on my Ubuntu machine.
The issue is the following:
I have been using docker for some time without problems. I have tons of images and volumes there. Now one day after restart when I try to start my project using `docker-compose up` I get error that port is in use:
`Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8011: bind: address already in use.`
Now the thing is there is no project apart from mine that is using this port. I checked `docker ps` and there are no containers up. Not even portainer that I use to manage images and containers. It seems that there is another docker-daemon running on my machine or other version of docker. It might be the case that I botched installation at the beginning and now it came back to haunt me.

What I tried:

1. Uninstalled snap version of docker.
2. Restarted using `sudo systemctl restart docker`
3. Reinstalled docker completelly- it worked for a while but I lost all containers and images and again after a while it started showing me different docker with different images and no volumes while at the same time the ports for my apps where blocked because the docker I was using previously still was up.

Is there a way to list running docker-daemons/engines/instances and choose which one to use in the system?

Comment: It's very very unlikely you have multiple Docker daemons, or that a second Docker would cause this problem.  If you did the `$DOCKER_HOST` environment variable would select which one, but you probably don't have this set.

Comment: Somehow I have two of them though. One of them is full of images and other one has like 12 images. Also volumes dont match. They change at random. Sometimes one of the switches off when my machine is running idle for a longer time. Then when I restart the other becomes the docker daemon that I can use on the system. Extremely weird situation.

Comment: How can you tell?  Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: there was just another person having 2 times docker running somehow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69065443/docker-error-bind-address-already-in-use-for-any-ip

Comment: Why observing `tcp 0.0.0.0:8011: bind: address already in use` resulted in the conclusion that there are two docker instances? Just something is listening on port 8011. Does your application uses `SO_REUSEADDR`?

Comment: @KamilCuk it resulted because it happened after I put the machine to sleep, with the app running on port 8011 using docker-compose. When I started up again I was sure than I could be able to use the app again, but docker switched off so I had to restart machine and after restarting when I checked there were no containers on the docker and no images at all. However the ports for the apps that were up before restart were still in use. Now after another restart I got randomly the docker with all my previous images and volumes back...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have two dockerds? It is very possible, but very uncommon.

With an `lsof -n -P|grep TCP|grep 8011` or so, you can list what is listening already on 8011. This "userland proxy" is a docker thingy: if you publish 8011 of a container, docker starts a process listening on 8011 and forwarding the connections to the container. The likely cause is that you have already running something on 8011. It does not matter, which dockerd (or another, non-docker process) is listening already on 8011.

There is no specific command to list the dockerd(s) of your system. You can list the running dockerds, for example, by a `ps uxa|grep dockerd` command. After that, an `lsof -n -p <pid> -P` will show, where are they listening.

The most likely cause of your problem is that another container is already using your 8011.

Comment: The thing is I use this port 8011 for this app when I start docker. I actually checked that it is indeed this thing still up on this port. Same with port 5432 for my postgres database. It is not running in my "todays" docker, but I had it up "yesterday" with whole project. Now when I start it again with docker-compose up it is being blocked by the postgres from this other docker-daemon environment.

Comment: I had to manually kill the processes that were taking up my apps ports. There is nothing else that could use up those ports except my apps. Even portainer was not running on this second docker-daemon that had no containers up, but when I checked what was taking up my 9000 port it was `docker-pr`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like both docker daemons where listening at `/var/run/docker.sock` and the requests were randomly distributed causing the inconsistency.

Comment: Exactly what I am thinking, but is there a way to solve this without reinstalling ubuntu?